# How do I repair latch lock that has unscrewed?

Tags: lock

In the image, part C has detached from part A. I assume that this happened because part A moved slightly each time the door was opened. Part C cannot be screwed onto part A because of the square shape. The only way that it can be reattached is by turning part A. The problem is that there seems to be no way to turn part A.

Part B is a spring that goes over part A when reattaching.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Turned out that there was a screw at the other end of the bolt that release the two metal sides which allowed me to remove the plate and attach pliers to part A and screw part C back on.